# SCSS - Is there a 'self' indentifier?

Tags: css, sass

I want to add SCSS on the body, for default, and respecify them on the P and LI tags (not in total control of the site, and wanna stop plugins from hijacking my p's and li's).

So I have to do something like this

```
body{
  color:#000;
  p,li{
    color:#000;
  }
}
```

But that makes some ugly repetition. So is there a thing in SCSS that refers to self or something like that? So at the end I could have the same styles on body, body p, and body li?

Something like

```
body{
  [self],p,li{color:#000;}
}
```

Comment: What kind of `<p>`s and `<li>`s are not under the body tag?

Comment: Well its to set a default for also all other texts that might be on the page in any other tag like divs.

Comment: Just setting body does the job. You're probably trying to give your CSS more specificity to override some styles that were more specific. This seems like a fragile way since other tags may also need more specificity. Using `!important` is not great but when dealing with third party styles, that can be the best way.

Comment: That is exactly what I do not want to do. Using important on a tag so wide like P will just bring problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body{
  &,p,li{color:#000;}
}
```

Comment: The colon will throw a compile error, you only need the `&`.

Comment: Sorry reverse it ^^

Comment: Im sorry . Im confused ^^